# Why @ngrx/effects trigger action but doesn't change the state?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have this effect:

```
loadIpInfo$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(loadIpInfo),
        concatMap((action: {ipInfoConfig: IpInfoConfig}) => {
            return this.ipService.getIpDetails(action.ipInfoConfig).pipe(
                map((ipInfoResponse) => {
                    this.store.dispatch(setErrorMessage({ message: '' }));
                    return loadIpInfoSuccess({ ipInfoResponse });
                }),
                catchError(() => {
                    return of(setErrorMessage({ message: 'Unknown error occurred. Please try again' }));
                })
            )
        })
    )
})
```

It triggers the action: **loadIpInfo** but doesn't change the state.

[image: Action]

[image: State]

Using breakpoints I saw that it didn't enter **concatMap**.

I've tried with different **rxjs.operators** such as: **exhaustMap**, **mergeMap**, **switchMap** but with the same result.

The purpose of this effect is to get static data from the ***config.json*** and call a **httpClient.get(..)** with this information.

What am I doing wrong?

- Here you can find the [github repository](https://github.com/rsteaburdea/online-store-ui/tree/develop/src/app/store/shared).
- I've also tried to add it to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/rsteaburdea/online-store-ui/tree/develop) but is not working there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without having a reproduction.

Make sure to import the effects class in `EffectsModule.forRoot([])` or `EffectsModule.forFeature([])`.

Comment: Hi @timdeschryver, in the parent module which is lazy loaded I've already had ```EffectsModule.forFeature([SharedEffects])```, also I've just edited the post with a **github url**.

Comment: I believe the action is dispatched before the lazy loaded module is registered.

Answer (score 0):

I have **app.module.ts** which is the parent module and **nav.module.ts** which is a *lazy-loaded* module.

I have also the **SharedEffects**, I've added it to the **nav.module.ts** with `forFeature(..)`, but the component that triggered the effect was **app.component.ts** so it had to be added to **app.module.ts** with `forRoot(..)`